# redux-saga race between "take"s with payload conditional

Tags: redux-saga

I have

```
yield race([
  take('ACTION_ONE'),
  take('ACTION_TWO')
])
```

but I want to specify that the condition for `ACTION_ONE` finishing is that the action payload has a specific value. How can I do this?

Comment: I would move that conditional logic into whatever dispatches `'ACTION_ONE'`

Answer (score 3):

You can pass a callback function in the take.

```
const { action1, action2 } = yield race({
  action1: take(action => action.type === 'ACTION_ONE' && action.value === value),
  action2: take(action => action.type === 'ACTION_TWO' && action.value === value),
})

if (action1) {
   console.log('action1 fired')
}

if (action2) {
   console.log('action2 fired')
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Probably you need to define a new saga to handle the 'ACTION_ONE' and put it in the race. Something like this:

```
function* actionOneSaga() {
  let notFound = true;
  while(notFound) {
    const action = yield take('ACTION_ONE');
    if (action.payload === 'SOME_VALUE') {
      doSomethingWithYourValue(action.payload);
      notFound = false;
    }
  }
}
```

Then you can do:

```
yield race([
  take(actionOneSaga),
  take('ACTION_TWO')
])
```

Comment: Instead of setting `notFound = false;` you can also return a value and get it back as result of the `race` function